# Unknown Error When Installing python-rtmidi

Tags: python, midi

I am getting an error whenever I try to pip install python-rtmidi.

> `error: command C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181`

I can't find any information online about this error, what does it mean, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: "I can't find any info online on this error" - [really](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=link.exe+failed+with+exit+code+1181)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, the OP was probably searching for the entire error string. I believe it could be more or less unique due to the specific version

Answer (score 4):

I have tried installing rtmidi via `pip install rtmidi` and it is giving error on my system -

```
note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

So, i looked on internet and found this thread - https://github.com/SpotlightKid/python-rtmidi/issues/31

Where they have recommended installing `rtmidi` via `pip install python-rtmidi` command. So i have tried running this command on my laptop and it worked.

So, installing with `pip install python-rtmidi` works.

Comment: Care to explain why this would help? Please read [answer].

Comment: thank you so much!